# UseEffect only firing certain parts?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I'm trying to make it so that every time my search field changes, the code in useEffect executes. However, only `console.log('hi')` is being executed and none of the other code is.

I can't figure out why useEffect is selectively running the code. Why is this?

```
  useEffect(() => {
    console.log('hi')
    const filteredMonsters = monsters.filter(monster => {
      console.log('hi2')
      monster.name.toLowerCase().includes(searchField.toLowerCase());
    })
    setMonsters(filteredMonsters);
  }, [searchField])
```

Upon page load my console reads `'hi'` as expected. After typing in a value into the search box i see the following in console:

`hi`

`hi2`

After typing futher values into the search box i only see: `hi` being added and not `hi2`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you should return something from your filter function, change it to  something like this:

```js
useEffect(() => {
    console.log('hi')
    const filteredMonsters = monsters.filter(monster => {
     return monster.name.toLowerCase().includes(searchField.toLowerCase());
    })
    setMonsters(filteredMonsters);
  }, [searchField])
```